# Extract the Certificate files - Self-Signed Certificate

Tags: ssl, subdomain, self-signed-certificate

I have created a self-signed certificate on my Kubernetes cluster. I can now see that the certificate is showing the status READY = True. When I describe the secret of this certificate, I can see the below.

[Output of Secret](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DO0dG.jpg)

How do I extract the above files so I can use them to secure my website?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The keys are stored in the secret that we provide in the certificate.yaml file! I just had to do an edit secret and copied the content over.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).